# Can I initialize an empty numpy array as class attribute when using numba jitclass

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I know how to initialize and use fixed size numpy array in jitclass:

```py
spec = [
    ('N', int32)
    ('energy_list', types.Array(types.int32, 2, 'C')),
]
@jitclass(spec)
class Lattice:
    def __init__(self, N):
        self.N = N
        self.energy_list = np.ones((self.N, self.N), dtype=np.int32)
```

But is there a way to initialize an empty numpy array attribute, to be appended in the following methods:

```py
spec = [
    ('temp_list', ___?___)     # What should I put here?
]
@jitclass(spec)
class Lattice:
    def __init__(self, N):
        self.temp_list = np.array([])
```

I also cannot change the size of the numpy array if I initialize it in the `__init__()` function:

```py
@jitclass(spec)
class Lattice:
    def __init__(self, N):
        self.N = N
        self.new_list = np.ones((self.N, slef.N), dtype=np.int32)

    def new_method:
        self.new_list = np.append(self.new_list, 3)   # doesnt' work
        self.new_list = np.array([])    # doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

> `np.append(self.new_list, 3)   # doesnt' work`

This does not work because `self.new_list` is a **2D array**. In Numpy, this works because Numpy convert the input array to a 1D array before appending 1 item in this specific case. This behaviour is a bit bug prone as it will silently change the dimension of `self.new_list` resulting in subsequent error in other methods. Numba cannot do that because the **dimension of an array is a part of its type which cannot change**. One should not be confused between the shape and the dimension by the way.

> `self.new_list = np.array([])    # doesn't work`

This does not work because Numba cannot infer the type of `np.array([])`. This is because inference does not take into account the right hand side of the assignment expression. Doing such inference would cause Numba do be much slower and would also result in a much more complex code. You can fix this in your program by specifying the type of the array using the `dtype` parameter. This is a good practice as it prevent nasty implicit type conversions (which are known to be the root of many bugs hard to debug).

> `('temp_list', ___?___)     # What should I put here?`

You are the only one to know. Based on your question, I can just say that it should something like `types.Array(??, ??, 'C')`. Numpy choose to create an empty 1D array of `np.float64`. If you want the same behaviour, you can use the type `types.Array(type.float64, 1, 'C')`.

Note that using `np.append` in a loop to add few items is an anti-pattern and should never be used since it will recreate a new array every time (with a full copy). This is *very expensive*. Consider using lists in that case.